# How to set text value when I used pickerview with multiple components

Tags: swift

i implemented a demo of picker view with multiple component

when i set value to a text right 
i want output is

```
one 1
```

but it set

```
    one
    1
    2
    two
```

below is my code:

```
var  pickdata = [ ["one","Two"],
              ["1","2"]
            ]


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

  return pickdata.count
}   

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int 
{

    return 2
   }

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    return pickdata[component][row]
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
   activeTextfield.text = pickdata[component][row]
    print(pickdata[component][row])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @david mentioned changing the data structure to Dictionary will be the right approach. If you are looking for a easy hack then this code will help, though its not the best approach. for the output "one 1" and so on this can be useful

```
    var pickDataIndices = ["1", "2"]
    var pickData = ["one", "Two"]


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return pickData.count
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{

    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    return pickData[row]
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    activeTextfield.text = pickData[row]
    print("%@ %@",pickData[row], pickDataIndices[row])
}
```

Comment: Hi @AniketLokhande I am glad i could help. Would you mind upvoting the answer / accepting it as correct one

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `numberOfRowsInComponent` method to `return pick date[0].count`, since you are using a 2 dimensional array and you want to return the number of objects inside the inner arrays.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
  return pickdata[0].count
}
```

I would also recommend changing your data structure to a `Dictionary<String,String>`, it seems more sufficient for this problem that a 2 dimensional Array.

`var pickData = ["one":1,"two":2]`